# Is there a way I can track only the first change to a field in django models?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a `django-model` with the name `Post`

```py
class Post(models.Model, ModelMeta):
    ...
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...
```

I want to update the `date_published` field **only once**, for the first time when `publish` is set to `True`.
I have gone through [`Field Tracker`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker) and [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-save) but both of them update on every change. I probably need to use some sort of `flag` that is set when `publish` is set to `True`(for the first time). Since objects can be updated and queued again, publish is again set to `False` before approved by an admin.
I may probably add `flag` to the `model` but I think there probably should be a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not make `date_published` NULL-able, and mark something as "published" if it is not null. That makes it impossible to have something unpublished with a `date_published`, and vice-versa.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That would require updating `date_published` to `NULL` on update. I wanted to preserve the `date_published` even when the `object` gets `updated`. Making `date_published` `NULL` on update wouldn't actually be a right think to do.

Comment: Why you don't check date_published on publish change flag and if it isn't null, fill it. When publish flag change tor True, first check if date_published is null or not, then if it is null, fill it with current date. And also make date_published = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

Comment: @SaberSolooki This sounds like a good option. You may add this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I post my answer. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check date_published on publish change flag and if it isn't null, fill it. When publish flag change tor True, first check if date_published is null or not, then if it is null, fill it with current date. And also make `date_published = models.DateTimeField(null=True)`